# How to drag and drop element text into specific place in the textbox?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on the project which requires that HTML elements with text in the tree view to be drag and dropped to the textbox. Once the element is being dropped into the text box only the innerText of this element should be pasted into the particular place of the textbox. I am using AnularJS with this project.

I am listening to the mousedown, mousemove and mouseup events. My idea is to copy the innerText of the HTML element to the clipboard and AngularJS model on the 'mousedown' event and paste it into textarea on 'mouseup'.

The example code

```
        $scope.elementValue;

        elementsWithValuesToCopy.addEventListener('mousedown',
            function(event) {
                var element = event.currentTarget;
                var range = document.createRange();
                range.selectNode(element);
                window.getSelection().addRange(range);
                $scope.elementValue = document.execCommand('copy');
            });


        textAreaElement.addEventListener("mouseup",
            function(event) {
                ////Pasting value of elementValue into text box
            });
```

Above code does not work in my project the value is not getting assigned to the model.

Comment: can you provide more information ? UI, code ?  what event are to listening to?

Comment: sory for not providing all information at first, I am new to the StackOverflow community and this is in fact my first ever question, once again I appologize for not listing all information and thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

So 5 years later I was searching for a quick snippet of a similar functionality and found this question. As there was no answer, I switched to MDN docs and found a quite simple solution. So I considered to share it.

We just need to set data and correct mime to the dataTransfer object which is shared between drag-n-drop events:

```js
el.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.textContent); // for <textarea>
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', e.target.outerHTML); // for [contenteditable]
});
```

```js
document.querySelector('span.drag-me').addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.textContent);
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', e.target.outerHTML);
});
```

```css
span.drag-me {
  background: #ffc600;
}

.editor {
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 400px;
  height: 120px;
  display: grid;
}

.editor[contenteditable=true] {
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<span class="drag-me" draggable="true">Drag me to the boxes below!</span>

<div class="editor">
  <textarea>While dragging over you should observe the cursor indicating the place where dragged text will appear.</textarea>
</div>

<div class="editor" contenteditable="true">While dragging over you should observe the cursor indicating the place where dragged text will appear.</div>
```